# How to pass patch http request parameters via HTTParty gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, httparty

I am using the HTTParty gem to make a patch request to update an object via an API call as follows:

```
params = { first_name: "John"}

@options = {params: params}
@response = HTTParty.patch("http://localhost:3000/1/kites/4", @options)
```

But on the API side, within the update method that the above PATCH request is supposed to call I only see the following parameters available:

```
{"format"=>"json",
 "controller"=>"api/v1/kites",
 "action"=>"update",
 "version"=>"1",
 "id"=>"4"}
```

An error message is passed back to the @response for pasrsing.

What happened to first_name and/or how do I call HTTParty.patch appropriately if that is indeed what is causing the loss of the parameters passed to the API?

EDIT:

As it turns out, if I do

```
@options = {query: params}
```

that will work but only if I keep a query under a certain size....

Comment: Can you share the whole response hash? puts @response.inspect and share it.

Comment: @EkiEqbal - response = nil

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what your 'patch' action does exactly in your API but the [documentation](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L509) says that you need to pass a URL and params in a `body:` key, like so:

`HTTParty.patch('site/your_url', body: { key1: value, key2: value })`

Alternalitvely, you can pass the params in `query:` key which appends the params to the URI.

`HTTParty.patch('site/your_url', query: { key1: value, key2: value })`